# Matplotlib disappearing plots multiple axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, anaconda

I am working on a project to graph multiple graphs against a variety of axis. But I am unable to actually render any graphs successfully using the matplotlib guide for how to plot multiple axis in python.

I have already seen the working maptlotlib guide. I am trying to now modify it for my own purposes so I need to know the minimal level of work necessary to make any type of graph display.

Particularly, could someone explain to me what I need to do to make:

```
from sympy import * 
from matplotlib import pyplot as p #plot system
import numpy as np #for creating arrays fast
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d #for drawing curves between points
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA



transmissionTable1 = {"name":"SidTest" ,"date":"NULL","runID":9999 ,"port":9999, "users":[60,120,240] ,"ROUTING":[0.11, 0.246, 4.096] ,  "Disc01":[0.301,0.639,4.428], "Transaction per Sec":[12.12,23.18,31.81]}

host = host_subplot(111,axes_class=AA.Axes)
p.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
axialShift = 60

basis = transmissionTable1["users"] #vary by users

t1  = host.twinx()
t2 = host.twinx()

p.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])

p.show()
```

succesfully render the graph of y = x interpolated at x = 1,2,3? Why is the act of creating host.twinx() blocking the ability to render graphs

Comment: There's only one plot statement in this and it renders correctly for me: a line from (1,1) to (3,3). I recommend: [a] take out the `transmissionTable1`, use data as simple as `[1,2,3]` (but different lists each time -- easier to debug); [b] don't mix up the object style in which you create axes `t1` and `t2` with the pyplot style in which you `p.plot()` into whatever context happens to be current.

Comment: @cphlewis are you saying the exact code I posted up there worked? Because it doesn't work for me. I get a plot but i don't get anything on the plot itself. Just a blank grpah

Comment: The advice of @cphlewis is very good, as to not mixing the object style and the pyplot style.  Doing so is not robust, and quite often leads to different performance on different machines.

Comment: Yes, frogeyedpeas, I got a plot with one diagonal blue line on it, exactly as expected.

Comment: That's... definitely not what i was expecting, based on my machine. I guess then @Ajean's comment really comes to play